# Power supply specs for an Avaya 4624IP VoIP Handset?

Tags: voip, telephony

I've got an Avaya 4624 IP VoiP phone that I've ordered a power supply for, but it's still likely a week away, and I'd like to test now.

I can't find the power requirements anywhere. I was hoping someone reading this might have a power brick to these things and be able to give me the stats. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1151B1 Power Supply
The 1151B1 Power Supply provides power to Avaya IP telephones when PoE is not compatible or PoE is not available.

Features
Universal AC Input
RJ45 type connectors accept D8W modular plug cables
**Input 100-240 V, 50-60 Hz, 500-250 mA**
**Output +48 V, 417 mA**
Power LED
Includes power cable and D8W line cord